# Export function* in javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

What is the difference between the following two ways of exporting modules in ES6 ?

```
export function myFunc() {
    ···
}
export function* myGeneratorFunc() {
    ···
}
```

Comment: Those aren't two different ways of *exporting* functions. One is a regular function and the other is a [generator function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*)

Comment: while there are syntax variations for export modules, there is no difference between the way those modules export.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of those statements exports a function, and the other one exports a generator function.